# Null check in a list in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I use null check inside a list in Thymeleaf.
I have the following

```
<tr th:each="idBean : ${idBeanLst}">

                <td th:text="${idBean.identifierId}"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.idNumber}"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.issueLocation}"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.issueDate}"></td>
                <td th:text="${idBean.expiryDate}"></td>
```

idBeanLst is the list that contains identifierBean.Now I want to show the result only if idBean.idNumber !=null.How to put this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `if` statement at the end `tr` tag

```
<tr th:each="idBean : ${idBeanLst}" th:if="${idBean.idNumber != null}">
            <td th:text="${idBean.identifierId}"></td>
            <td th:text="${idBean.idNumber}"></td>
            <td th:text="${idBean.issueLocation}"></td>
            <td th:text="${idBean.issueDate}"></td>
            <td th:text="${idBean.expiryDate}"></td>
</tr>
```